# Socket.io + C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, socket.io

I'm writing a server in C and I was wondering if I could use html as my client and communicate with the server in C via sockets, using socket.io on the client side. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. It doesn't matter which language the server/client is written in. They just send/receive network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. They are just data transfer, no matter what language at client/server side.

Comment: I think he means javascript (socket.io) and not HTML.